# Why does an error occur when I try to test if a member variable (string) in a class is empty?

Tags: c++11

I'm working on a project and need to test one of my class' member variables to verify that the user did indeed enter a string.

I've also tried using (patronName == '') and (patronName == "") but have had no luck.

Edit: Using "\n" fixes the error but the program ends without allowing the user to enter a name.

```
std::string Restaurant::getPatronName()
{
     bool controlFlag = true;
do
{
    getline(std::cin,patronName);

    if ((std::cin.fail()) || (patronName == '\n'))  
    {
        std::cout << "You must enter a name!" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else
    {
        controlFlag = false;
    }
} while (controlFlag);

return patronName;
}
```

The function should read and store the name entered by the user into patronName. When trying to build, I get an error that says "no match for 'operator=='". Could this be because the object called in main is a pointer of type Restaurant?

Comment: You know where's the problem, so what are you even asking of? You're trying to compare a string against character. Put `\n` in double quotes: `"\n"`.

Comment: Using "\n" gets rid of the error but the program just ends without letting the user enter a name

Answer (score 1):

Besides the type mismatch between the character `'\n'` and the `std::string` `patronName`, we can find at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline that `std::getline(input, str, delim);`

> Extracts characters from input and appends them to `str` until […] the next available input character is `delim`, […], in which case **the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to `str`.**

So there won't be any `'\n'` character, if `delim` is the newline, in the first place.

You can use [`std::basic_string::empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) to check if a string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

What happens with `'\n'` is you are comparing a string with a char, which, i suspect, there is no operator== defined for this case. If you are sure the string isn't empty, you can call operator[] `formerName[0]`, which returns a char.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `patronName == "\n"` because you cannot compare string and character